# Sql server encryption by password / certificate?

Tags: sql-server

When im using

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SecureSymmetricKey
    WITH ALGORITHM = DESX
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = N'StrongPassword';


DECLARE  @str NVARCHAR(100)
SET @str = 'lala';

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SecureSymmetricKey
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = N'StrongPassword';
```

**Whom** itrying to protect the data **from** ?

the data being sent from client to server ? ( the data is being sent by plaing text - i cant activate sql commands before sending the data...)
**or** people who has access to the sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to protect your data in the database from people who either have access to any one of:

- the SQL Server instance
- the data files
- the backup files

So if someone steals your backup tapes, they won't have a database of unencrypted SSNs or Credit Card numbers to sell on the black market.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If a hacker got my data files, is there a way he can see the password :  N'StrongPassword' ??

Comment: Im asking you this because i want to make sure he wont be able to read the data - and if he can extract the password - he will be able to see the real data...

Comment: I can't think of a way to retrieve the password - I believe it's hashed with a seed, not stored in plaintext, so it shouldn't be retrievable.